# Python: unicode error with getting an input

Tags: python-3.x, syntax-error

So I keep getting this error whilst trying to run my program:

File "C:/Users/use/.spyder-py3/minip.py", line 277
    get_input = input("Continue? Y\N:")
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 11-12: malformed \N character escape

I cannot figure out why it's giving me an error, everything seems right to me. 
**Just putting it out there, I'm only a couple weeks into my coding class so I'm not very advanced in anything**              ^

```
        p1.betWin(betInput, otherBet)
        print("You won:$",otherBet + betInput)
        p1.show()
        p2.show()
        get_input = str(input("Continue? Y\N:"))
        continueGame(get_input)
```

definition for continueGame

```
        if get_input == 'y' or get_input == 'Y' or get_input == 'yes' or get_input == 'Yes':
            run = True
            return run
        if get_input == 'n' or get_input == 'N' or get_input == 'no' or get_input == 'No':
            run = False
            return run
```

Answer (score 1):

The `\` character is called an ["escape" character](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/escapes.html), used to encode characters such as newlines (`\n`). If you want a literal `\` then you should do:

```
"Continue? Y\\N:"
```

Comment: Ahh, makes total sense now, I feel kind of dumb now that I look at that, I thought it was giving me an error initially because I had used \n earlier in the code to print out something, didn't think of the Y\N case. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Was a simple (as the error said) syntax problem, was trying to get an input from a user using Y\N (yes or no) but forgot about the \n use.